# Which event causes such a kink in gradient descent?

Tags: gradient-descent

I'm running gradient descent on a continuous function and I observe this pattern:
[image]

What can cause such a sudden kink? Why does the Loss keep increasing after it? I understand issues related to a learning rate that is too large, but this does not seem to be the case.

The parameter also turns abruptly (it's a complex-valued parameter, or we can think of it as a pair of parameters):
[image]

For completeness, here's the norm of the gradient (there's no large jump as if there was a cliff, [see fig. 8.3 pag. 285](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/optimization.html))
[image]

Comment: What is the function that you are trying to minimize?

Comment: it's a bit complicated to write explicitly in full, but it's an inner product between a complex vector $\mathbf{u}$ and a vector $\mathbf{v}$ transformed by the parametrized unitary matrix U(z):
$\mathrm{loss}(z) = -|\langle \mathbf{u}^* , U(z) \mathbf{v}\rangle|^2$

Comment: There may be an error in the formulation of the gradient computation.